# Powershell how to filter objects based on child objects of child objects

Tags: powershell, children, where-object

In powershell I've got a COM object which has several child COM objects which themselves have child com objects.  I want to be able to get the top level object if the child of the child has a particular property.  Unfortunately many of the objects don't have names and the structure doesn't make much sense to me.

I can get there potentially with a loop but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

When I put this into powershell

`$jobobj.steps`

I get the following output:

```
Name                        :
Value                       : System.__ComObject
Description                 :
AccessType                  : 0
ExportAsEnvironmentVariable : False
ReadOnly                    : False
Use                         : 1
Volatile                    : False
Secured                     : False
Options                     :

Name                        : JobStepComment
Value                       :
Description                 :
AccessType                  : 0
ExportAsEnvironmentVariable : False
ReadOnly                    : False
Use                         : 1
Volatile                    : False
Secured                     : False
Options                     :
```

Then I put in
`$jobobj.Steps[1].value`

Which returns a bunch of properties as objects like above.  I won't provide the full list as it would fill the page but here is a small subset.

```
Name                        : Values
Value                       : System.__ComObject
Description                 :
AccessType                  : 0
ExportAsEnvironmentVariable : False
ReadOnly                    : False
Use                         : 1
Volatile                    : False
Secured                     : False
Options                     :

Name                        : Bindings
Value                       : System.__ComObject
Description                 :
AccessType                  : 0
ExportAsEnvironmentVariable : False
ReadOnly                    : False
Use                         : 1
Volatile                    : False
Secured                     : False
Options                     :
```

The below steps get me to what I want but I'm very much assuming I'm picking up the right object in the array by hardcoding the [1] and [2].

Is there any way to filter the $jobobj.Steps Value based on the properties of sub object of sub objects so I don't have to assume I'm choosing the right number in the array?

```
$Bindings = $jobobj.Steps[1].value | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "bindings"}
$Items = $Bindings.value | where-object {$_.Name -eq "Items"}
$Config = ($items.value[2]).value | where-object {$_.Name -eq "Value" -and $_.Value -EQ '${CONNECTIONSTRING_CORE}'}
```

Comment: $jobobj.Steps | Where-Object {$_.value.Name -eq "bindings"} - should help or?

Comment: I managed it with a similar way.

$Config = ($jobobj.steps |   foreach{$_.Value} | where -Property Name -eq 'Bindings' | foreach{$_.Value} | where -property Name -eq 'Items'| foreach{$_.Value}) | where-object {$_.Value | where-object {$_.Value -eq 'Configuration.Connections[0].ConnectionString'}}